# Regularized canonical correlation analysis using the SVD approach

Tags: pca, references, regularization, svd, canonical-correlation

I am trying to implement the canonical correlation analysis algorithm of Golub and Zha (described [here](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/na/m/92/13/NA-M-92-13.pdf)), but am running into a well known issue with canonical correlation analysis in that I repeatedly find only trivial solutions (canonical correlations are 1 for all canonical vectors).  The method for getting around this problem for other formulations of the problem involves regularization of the covariances, but this method does not apply to the approach linked above since the authors do not use the respective covariances: they use an SVD to decompose $U_X^TU_Y$, where $U_X$ is a basis for the dataset $X$ and $U_Y$ is a basis for the dataset $Y$.  Has anyone come across a solution to the problem described above?  I have not and would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: Hmm, I've once implemented a CC-algorithm, based on a proposal of S. Mulaik in his monography on factor analysis and had never seen such problems. Don't know whether there is something interesting for you in this?

Comment: The paper is about "canonical correlations of matrix pairs". Is it different from classic CCA? In what way? You read the article...

Comment: No, my understanding is that it's just an alternate formulation of classical CCA.  This view is also shared by these authors: http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/avron13.pdf.

Comment: +1. I think there should be a way to do it, but I cannot say straight away. I will try to think about it in the following days, so check back.

Comment: @munchkin, let me know if you are still around, I can provide the solution.